# How to change desktop background via terminal on openSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, wallpaper, susestudio

I am using SUSE Studio to make a custom version of openSUSE with the KDE 4 desktop. A small problem is that the background is set by default to the chameleon light bulb. I suspect I can fix this manually by adding a line to the script that runs at the end of a build. So, what is this command, if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

The default wallpaper is automatically configured when the user first logs in. You can change what the default gets set to by editing `/usr/share/config/kdesktoprc` or some such file (that is the file on my KDE 4 system; it may vary for OpenSUSE). Something like this should work:

```
WALLPAPER=/path/to/new/wallpaper
sed -ir "s:\(Wallpaper\)=.*:\1=$WALLPAPER:" /usr/share/config/kdesktoprc
```

If you want to do the same for end-users already configured, change the path of the file to `$HOME/.kde/share/config/kdesktoprc` (possibly `$HOME/.kde4`). You'll need to restart `plasma-shell` after you make that change.

See also [information about setting up a KDE kiosk](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Kiosk/Introduction), which may be of some use.

Comment: That would be good, but how can I do it so that it's pre-packaged? Should I replace the file in the OS itself?

Comment: Another way is: `dcop kdesktop KBackgroundIface setWallpaper /path/to/mywallpaper.jpg 6` (Taken from LinuxForums)

Comment: Also @PixelSpark in SuSE Studio, you used to be able to have scripts run during Kiwi, poke around there.

Comment: @SailorCire Is that a command to run or a way to edit the file mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @SailorCire Doesn't give me the option. Only on every boot and upon building.